# Why do Binomial Coefficients work for ordering items?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

I'm working on a question from Harvard's [Stat 110 course](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/sites/projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_1.pdf).

The question is the following:

> 3(a) How many paths are there from the point (0, 0) to the point (110, 111) in
> the plane such that each step either consists of going one unit up or one unit to the
> right?

I understand how to answer this: $${221 \choose 110} \equiv {221 \choose 111}$$

And I understand the reasoning:

> You can place the movements up and right in a sequence. Selecting the positions of the movements right in this sequence automatically specifies the movements up too. (Likewise for the converse).

This makes sense to me intuitively. But I feel like there's a deeper explanation, which I can't find anywhere online.

What is the deeper explanation? Why do Binomial Coefficients work for problems like this?

Comment: Fascinating! So, how did people conclude this is correct? Just by trying many examples and seeing that it was? Or is it so intuitive that no one has proven it mathematically?

Comment: Do you understand why a binomial coefficient counts the number of ways to select the positions of the word "right" in a sequence of "right" and "up"? If not, the explanation about the sequence isn't "reasoning" for the binomial coefficients at all. But you call it "reasoning". So people will have trouble understanding the question, because we can't figure out which things you know and which you don't.

Comment: @DavidK This is what I understand. Binomial coefficients count the number of possible distinct sub groups (of size k) of a larger group (of size n). This is important in this problem, because the ups are interchangeable with the ups, and the rights are interchangeable with the rights. So you don't want to overcount permutations. Given that, is the reasoning I've given sound?

Comment: If you have $n$ distinct objects, then $\binom nm$ is the number of ways to choose exactly $m$ of the $n$ things. This is relevant here because we have a set of $n$ positions in the sequence and we are choosing exactly $m$ of them.

Comment: @DavidK Okay, so you have to consider it as choosing m distinct (numbered) positions out of n possibilities. Instead of choosing m rights out of n combined rights and ups?

Comment: Yes, that's how I would count it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a distance of 221 segments to cross,110 of which will be steps to the right, and 111 will be steps vertically.

We could put the vertical segments and the horizontal segments onto scrabble tiles and how many ways are there to select scrabble tiles…

This is the exact same process of

$(a+b)^{221} = (a+b)(a+b)\cdots(a+b)$

The coefficient of the $a^{110}b^{111}$ term counts the number of ways to pick the right number of $a$’s vs. $b$’s from the available buckets.

Comment: How did someone come to this conclusion? I guess that's the part I'm struggling with. What insight led someone to apply this idea to a problem like the one I've stated above?

Comment: For simplicity, imagine you want to count the number of paths that go up 3 times and right 2 times. You could go up 3 times initially and right 2 times after that, which you can write as $UUURR$. Or you could do up, up, right, up, right, which is $UURUR$. Or you could do up, up, right, right, up, which is $UURRU$. Or you could do $RURUU$, which means right, up, right, up, up. And so on. We can see that the number of possibilities is the same as counting how many ways we can place 3 U's and 2 R's in a line, which gives us $\binom{5}{2}$. A similar reasoning applies to your particular example.

Comment: Combinatorics is essentially the math of counting stuff.  It is about as old of an area of mathematical discovery as there is.  And, if you were a person researching better ways to count stuff, it would be natural to see a variety of problems as counting problems and attempt to apply your techniques as widely as possible.